# what is the right waay to get traffic on a port in a computer?

Tags: mongodb, networking

When I bind my Database (MongoDB) to 0.0.0.0:5000, and I send a query from another PC connected to the same local network, using: the DB computer's ipv4 address and port 5000, I'm able to access the database.

However, if the Database is not running on 0.0.0.0, the connection fails. I'm sorry if this is a noob question, if any1 could explain or point me in the right direction it would be great!

Is running on 0.0.0.0 the right thing to do? if not, how do I get the traffic from my comp's port 5000 to be diverted to 127.0.0.1 (or something similar) port: 5000?

Comment: Default port for MongoDB is 27017, which port did you configure?

Comment: hello @Wernfied Domscheit, thank you for your response. Yes the default port is 27017, even when running on 27017; im not able to access the DB if I do not bind it to 0.0.0.0:27017, what is the significance of this 0.0.0.0 and if I do not bind it to 0.0.0.0, what settings must i add so it connects?

Comment: With the `bind` parameters you tell the MongoDB "listen for new connection initiated from IP ..." Setting it to `0.0.0.0` (or `bindIpAll: true`) means, accept connection from any IP. It is some kind like a firewall - but certainly it does not replace a firewall.

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask would be: how can I access it without binding it to 0.0.0.0? How to I send traffic that is received on my system 192.168.0.1:27017 to mongo db that is on the same system 127.0.0.1:27017‽

Comment: Note, 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, i.e. always the current host.,

Comment: yes, how can I send the DB connection/query that comes from the LAN to my laptop on 192.168.0.1:27017 to the MongoDB database running on the same said laptop on 127.0.0.1:27017?

Comment: is there any routing rule or something I need to set up for this to happen?

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about. As said 127.0.0.1 is your own address - **always**! How do you connect to your MongoDB? How do you start it?